# Highcharts TypeScript Boost module

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts

I want to use the TypeScript definitions for the Highcharts module Boost

The definitions exist as:

```
// Type definitions for Highcharts 4.2.6 (boost module)
// Project: http://www.highcharts.com/
// Definitions by: Daniel Martin <http://github.com/inad9300>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

import { Static } from "highcharts";

declare function HighchartsBoost(H: Static): Static;
export = HighchartsBoost;
export as namespace HighchartsBoost;
```

when i try to import them as either of the following:

```
import { HighchartsBoost } from "highcharts/modules/boost";
import * as HighchartsBoost from "highcharts/modules/boost";
```

I get the error: Module resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should use: `import HighchartsBoost from "highcharts/modules/boost";`